# Que registro se repite mas veces SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas

Buenas tardes tengo Tres tablas en sql quiero saber cual es el producto mas vendido OJO no necesito tener el stock como dato

```
create table Producto(
id_prod int primary key,
nombre varchar(15)
Precio decimal(2,2)
 )
 create table Venta(
 idventa int primary key,
 fecha date
 )
create table Detalle(
id_detalle int primary key,
idventa int,
id_prod int   
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Olvidaste la columna 'cantidad' en la tabla 'Detalle'?. 
Agrupa por el identificador del producto en la tabla 'Detalle', ordena -de manera descendente- por la cuenta de elementos que contiene cada grupo y toma las filas que correspondan con el valor de cuenta más alto. Si cuentas con la columna 'cantidad', en lugar de utilizar la función COUNT() ocupa la función SUM(cantidad).

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES p.nombre, COUNT(*) AS [Cantidad]
FROM
    Detalle d
    INNER JOIN Producto p ON d.id_prod = p.id_prod
GROUP BY d.id_prod, p.nombre
ORDER BY Cantidad DESC;
GO
```

Comment: uhmm esta en lo correcto pero lo que hace esa consulta es mostrar solo el primero que tenga el maximo valor ,pero si fuera el caso hubiera otro producto con la misma cantidad de ventas?

Comment: En la respuesta hago la siguiente acotación: "...y toma las filas que correspondan con el valor de cuenta más alto", y de ello se encarga la instrucción WITH TIES: muestra los empates producidos

Comment: Gracias de antemano por la ayuda Hermano :D